# Kendo UI Window + PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have this code in my View

```
@model IEnumerable<mvcAmerica.Models.Art> 
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
              .Name("window")
              .Title("Agregar Detalle")
              .Draggable()
              .Visible(false)
              .Actions(actions => actions.Close())
              .Events(ev => ev.Close("onClose"))
              .Width(600)
              .Height(600)
              .Content(() =>
                  {
                      @Html.RenderPartial("_ArtViewCreate");
                  })


)
<span id="undo" class="k-button">Click here to open the window.</span>

<script>
    function onClose() {
        $("#undo").show();
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#undo").bind("click", function() {
                $("#window").data("kendoWindow").open();
                $("#undo").hide();
            });
    });
</script>
```

but the result is unexpected, the partial view render in my main page, not in Kendo UI Window

[image: Main Page Not Kendo UI Window]

Someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't use content instead I just did this. `.Visible(false)` like you have and then on some event fire this function.

```
function clientLaunchWindow() {

     var window = $("#Name").data("kendoWindow");

     window.refresh({
             url: "/Order/LaunchManualProposalWindow"        
     });      
     window.center();
     window.open();

 };

  public ActionResult LaunchManualProposalWindow()
    {           
        return PartialView("_CreateManualProposal");
    }
```

Comment: Don't work, i posted my code down, any suggest? Thanks for the reply

Comment: i delete de .open() from clientLaunchWindow() example and work fine, thanks very much.... now, i try that windows open several time

Answer (score 0):

You can use LoadContentFrom and specify Action and Controller.  The action will have its own partial View attached to it.  See [here](http://kirandhappuri.wordpress.com/2014/12/12/kendo-ui-window-a-modal-dialog-with-kendo-grid-mvc-controller-action-partial-view-and-ajax-calls-to-refresh-data/) for details.